# Cómo capturo el audio de una ventana de WPF o la salida de CSCore en c#?

Tags: c#, wpf, audio, networking, sonido

Hice un reproductor de música en WPF usando la librería [CSCore](https://github.com/filoe/cscore). Ahora quiero agregar una función que permita transmitir el audio hacia otra instancia del reproductor en tiempo real (algo así como una radio) a través de internet. Me podría fijar después como hacer lo de la transmisión, pero primero necesito saber cómo obtener los bytes de la salida de audio. Pido ayuda porque estoy perdido, estuve investigando y solo encontré [como transmitir el audio entero del escritorio](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q-HCap0TJ2M) (que no lo probé, y es en windows forms). Eso no me sirve en este caso porque quiero escuchar música y transmitirla a las respectivas instancias del reproductor con las que se conecten mis amigos mientras hablamos por Discord. Así que, si transmito todo el audio del escritorio, además de escuchar la música se escucharían a si mismos. Y si estoy jugando a algún juego también se escucharía. Cualquier ayuda es bienvenida, y mucho más si me pueden encaminar para saber dónde buscar la info. Gracias de antemano!

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gracias a la [respuesta de Max](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71857026/16211100) en mi post en StackOverflow en inglés y un buen tiempo de leer y leer documentación y ejemplos, finalmente aprendí cómo obtener una copia del buffer de un `IWaveSource`.

Comparto una clase que hice que tiene 2 eventos: `SingleByteIntercepted` (se invoca cada vez que se lee un byte del buffer y devuelve una copia de ese byte) y `BufferIntercepted` (se invoca cada vez que se lee todo el buffer y devuelve una copia del buffer entero)

```
class BufferInterceptor : WaveAggregatorBase
{
    public event EventHandler<byte[]> BufferIntercepted;
    public event EventHandler<byte> SingleByteIntercepted;

    private readonly object _lockObj = new object();

    public BufferInterceptor(IWaveSource source): base(source)
    {
    }

    public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        int read = base.Read(buffer, offset, count);
        lock (_lockObj)
        {
            byte[] interceptedBuffer = new byte[read];
            for (int i = offset; i < read; i++)
            {
                interceptedBuffer[i - offset] = buffer[i];
                if (SingleByteIntercepted != null)
                    SingleByteIntercepted.Invoke(this, interceptedBuffer[i - offset]);
            }
            if (BufferIntercepted != null)
                BufferIntercepted.Invoke(this, interceptedBuffer);
        }
        return read;
    }
}
```

Para interceptar el buffer de un `IWaveSource` usando esa clase, en su declaración hacen lo siguiente:

```
IWaveSource source = CodecFactory.Instance.GetCodec(archivo)
            .ChangeSampleRate(48000);
var _bufferInterceptor = new BufferInterceptor(source);
```

Después se suscriben al evento que más les convenga:

```
//Evento para interceptar cada byte leido
_bufferInterceptor.SingleByteIntercepted += (s, a) => {
    byte _ByteInterceptado = a;

    //Todo lo que quieras hacer con el byte va en esta función
};

//Evento para interceptar todo el buffer
_bufferInterceptor.BufferIntercepted += (s, a) => {
    byte[] _BufferInterceptado = a;

    //Todo lo que quieras hacer con el buffer va en esta función
}
```

Finalmente, para reproducir los archivos igualan `source` a `_bufferInterceptor` e inicializan un `ISoundOut` con `source`. El código final para interceptar el buffer cada vez que es leído quedaría así:

```
IWaveSource source = CodecFactory.Instance.GetCodec(archivo)
            .ChangeSampleRate(48000);
var _bufferInterceptor = new BufferInterceptor(source);

_bufferInterceptor.BufferIntercepted += (s, a) => {
    byte[] _BufferInterceptado = a;

    //Hacemos lo que queramos con el buffer interceptado
};
source = _bufferInterceptor;

ISoundOut reproductor = new WasapiOut();
reproductor.Initialize(source);
reproductor.Play();
```